# Decimal point / comma handling in pandas.read_clipboard

Tags: python, pandas, decimal-point

My script reads in data from the clipboard with `pd.read_clipboard()`. Being run on different computers and getting data from different inputs with either European decimal format (`1,23`) or international decimal format (`1.23`) I'd like to have some flexibility in the parsing process.

I could first read the content of the clipboard and decide according to some heuristics if I set `decimal='.'` or `decimal=','` as parameter to `pd.read_clipboard()`, but is there a more elegant way to achieve this? So far I haven't found an option to let pandas decide on the correct decimal separator.